# xaml: how to make visual studio to NOT process Carriage Return as space

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, removing-whitespace

A carriage return-line feed is processed as space if it appears before an inline element.
for ex, when writing in design mode:

```
<Run>abc</Run>
<Run>def</Run>
```

when the application runs, it will appear as:

abc def

and not as:

abcdef

Is there away to make visual studio to ignore the carriage return, so I will get the second example?

Comment: See the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page to learn how to post code correctly.

Comment: I bet it's not Visual Studio that you want to have the CR ignored. It's either the XML parser, or the XAML parser, or some other part of the WPF machinery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess you could try:

```
<Run>abc</Run><!--
--><Run>def</Run>
```

Kind of ugly though...

Answer (score 2):

No, this goes deeper.

XAML is XML and there is a "any sequence of whitespace becomes 1 space" rule there. Same as in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's impossible. But you could write both Runs in single line:

```
<Run>abc</Run><Run>edf</Run>
```